# VBA code to ignore #VALUE! in a Average Formula

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to modify my code below in order to Ignore cells which may have #VALUE!error. I've read on Web that =IFERROR((AVERAGE(K:K)*24),"") could fix it but it doesnt work.

Any idea how to solve it? Many thanks.

```
Sub insert_formulas()

Worksheets("Parsing").Range("N2").Formula = "=AVERAGE(J:J)*24" 
Worksheets("Parsing").Range("O2").Formula = "=AVERAGE(K:K)*24" 

END SUB
```

Comment: Which version(s) of Excel are you using? Your `IFERROR` works fine in Excel 2010. Are you remembering to double-up on the quote characters?   `Worksheets("Parsing").Range("N2").Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(J:J)*24,"""")"`

Comment: thanks a lot... u were right. missing to double up quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer after OP confirmed the problem was fixed.

Your IFERROR works fine in Excel 2010. Are you remembering to double-up on the quote characters?
`Worksheets("Parsing").Range("N2").Formula = "=IFERROR(AVERAGE(J:J)*24,"""")"`